# How does this link redirect?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, 404, http

Following this link in a web browser http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/cpp/post_retirement/eligibility.page eventually leads to https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/publicpensions/cpp/cpp-post-retirement/eligibility.html

However, my broken link checker marks it as a broken link. And sure enough, the response code for the original link is a 404. However I'm trying to make my link checker smarter and to follow any redirections to perhaps discover a working link in the end. My problem however is that I can't seem to figure out how the first redirection is done for the above link.

Looking at it in the Network tab of the Chrome inspector, it's easy to see the path it takes:

```
1) http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/cpp/post_retirement/eligibility.page
2) http://www.esdc.gc.ca/cgi-bin/op-so/err/404-fra.asp?servertype=apache&p=404;http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/cpp/post_retirement/eligibility.page
3) http://www.esdc.gc.ca/cgi-bin/op-so/err/redirect-outbound.asp?status=301%20Moved%20Permanently&redirect_path=/en/cpp/post_retirement/eligibility.page&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ecanada%2Eca%2Fen%2Fservices%2Fbenefits%2Fpublicpensions%2Fcpp%2Fcpp%2Dpost%2Dretirement%2Feligibility%2Ehtml
4) https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/publicpensions/cpp/cpp-post-retirement/eligibility.html
```

2 and 3 are HTTP 302 and 301 respectively, both with `Location` headers. Leaving good practices aside, that's fine, at least I can follow those. But what about the first one? I can't figure out what makes it jump from 1 to 2.

There's no response body at all so it can't be a JavaScript `window.location`. All that remains in my mind is an HTTP `Location` but I don't see any. What am I missing here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This type of question is better suited for [chat].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial request for `http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/cpp/post_retirement/eligibility.page` returns a page that contains the following...

```
<script>
window.location.replace("/cgi-bin/op-so/err/404-fra.asp?servertype=apache&p=404;http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/cpp/post_retirement/eligibility.page");
</script>
```

... which is how you get from step 1 to step 2. If you disable javascript, you'll get stuck on step 1 and can see the source.